# Is it a change of variable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Hi everyone: In a book I am reading, they make a sort of "substitution" like this: let $B(0,R)$ be a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ $(N\geq2)$ and $f$ a locally integrable function. Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $B(0,R)$.  They set 
$$\omega:=\int_{B(o,t)}d\mu(t)$$ and then they write 
$$\int_{B(0,R)}f(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{0}^{R}f(t)d\omega(t).(????)$$
Can someone explain this? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Do you assume that $f$ is rotationally invariant? For a function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, the expression $f(t)$ on the right-hand side is not even well-defined.

Comment: Let's assume this. Can you explain the steps? Thanks.